# Is this an axiom? "For a square, in order to draw a straight line between opposite diagonals, the line needs to pass through the mid-point."

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, axioms

I am just wondering if this is an axiom:

> For a square, in order to draw a straight line between opposite diagonals, the line needs to pass through the mid-point.

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Comment: That fact follows from other things

Comment: Why is it not though?

Comment: How do you prove it

Comment: What the heck is a midpoint of a square?  That is .... what is a reasonable definition?

Comment: Alright no need to rage bro

Comment: It is the centre of the square

Comment: What's the definition of the center of a square?

Comment: Well if you start from a corner of a square go halfway along to the middle of the line and then go perpendicular halfway in distance half way up to it in the direction of the lines adjacent to the line you started of with and then you will reach the centre

Comment: Then you must prove that this definition yields the same point if you use the other pair of sides....  If you draw the lines from this point to the four vertices its easy to prove the created triangles are congruent and that that sides form linear angles and therefore the center is also the intersection of the diagonals.

Comment: Might want to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_(geometry) In particular "For objects with several symmetries, the center of symmetry is the point left unchanged by the symmetric actions. So the center of a square, rectangle, rhombus or parallelogram is where the diagonals intersect, this being (amongst other properties) the fixed point of rotational symmetries. Similarly the center of an ellipse or a hyperbola is where the axes intersect. "

Answer (score 1):

It could be an axiom if you really wanted it to. You can make your axioms be whatever you want. But I have never seen any conventional treatment of geometry with such an axiom.

Comment: I agree. It COULD be an axiom of some form of geometry but it is not an axiom of Euclidean Geometry or any of the well known non-Euclidean geometries.

Comment: I was having Euclidean geometry in mind

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Again, you could probably include this as an axiom in a geometry of your own making, and then prove that your geometry ultimately becomes in Euclidean geometry as we all know it. There are, after all, many ways to axiomatize Euclidean geometry, some more popular than others. But as I said, I have never seen your statement as an axiom. I don't think there is any good reason to have it as an axiom. It's better to just use a conventional axiom set and leave your statement as a theorem.

Comment: Wow I didn't know I could do such things in maths. I am not a mathematician by the way

Comment: "Wow I didn't know I could do such things in maths"  Well, *someone* has to.  Math didn't just fall from the sky.  *Someone* had to invent it.  And if s/he could we can too.

Comment: I thought it discovers a priori truths we don't invent it but rather discover it

Comment: Yes, but we have to *interpret* them in a language of our devising.  If two "atoms" of meanings are equivalent (we can prove one from the other) which one we choose to be the axiom and which one we choose to be the result is entirely up to us.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 It's not so much about finding truths as it is about finding consequences. You have to start somewhere, from some base assumptions (we call them "axioms"), and then discover where they take you. Those axioms, however, are always invented by humans. Often they formally codify some intuitive notion we have discovered and want to study, but it is, nonetheless, ultimately we mathematicians who write them.

Comment: Hmm makes sense

Answer (score 1):

We must define the center of a square.

And if we define it as the unique point that is equidistance from the four vetices then we must first have a theorem that such a point exist and is unique.

And after that we can prove the diagonals pass through that point.

In standard Euclidean geometry we can prove it more or less like the following:

The set of all points equidistance from two opposite vertices is, by definition, the perpendicular bisector of of the diagonal.  So the any point that is equidistance from all four points would be the point of intersection of the two perpendicular bisectors of the the diagonals.  As two lines intersect at only one point this point is unique.

We can prove that the point of intersection of the two diagonals is equidistance from the four vertices (next paragraph).  So the point of intersection of the diagonals is this point.

A diagonal cuts a square into two triangles triangles.  As its a square these triangles have equal corresponding sides and they are congruent. And thus the base angles are equal (and they bisect a right angle and so are 45 degrees).  So the two diagonals cut the square into four triangles.  By symmetry and angle and component chasing it is easy to prove the four triangles are congruent. So the point of intersection is equidistance from the four vertices.

.....

ANd that's that.  In defining the *center* of a square as the unique point equidistance from all vertices, and in proving such a point exists and is unique, we proved that the diagonals intersect at the center.

Answer (score 0):

No, we needn't include that as an axiom because it's a theorem; I'll discuss just one way to prove it. If you give the vertices the usual Cartesian coordinates, one diagonal is $y=x$ while the other is $y=1-x$, so they both pass through the centre of the square, at $(1/2,\,1/2)$.

Comment: What's the definition of a center of a square?  And do centers exist for squares not placed and the origin of the coordinate system.  And is accepting that Cartesian coordinates are valid an axiom?  Which are the axioms and which are the conclusions?

Comment: @fleablood The path from axioms to where we want to go passes through many theorems and definitions, we can do it in various equivalent ways, and frankly there may be a more direct solution than proving we can add coordinates like this. But that's kind of the point: we're definitely not ending up at a standard axiom.